# Chrome Extension - Notification on Certain Web Pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to pop up a chrome notification whenever the user visits certain web pages e.g. 'www.amazon.com' or 'google.com' etc. The extension loads into chrome perfectly fine with no errors, but the notification doesn't pop up when I head to those specific pages.

I currently have the below scripts.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This extension was created with the awesome extensionizr.com",
  "homepage_url": "http://www.test.co.uk",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "page": "src/bg/background.html",
    "persistent": true
  },
  "options_page": "src/options/index.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "browser action demo",
    "default_popup": "src/browser_action/browser_action.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["notifications"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.amazon.com/*", "http://amazon.co.uk/*"],
      "js": ["js/script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**js/script.js**

```
if(onCertainWebsitesNeedNotificationAppearTrue) {
    // send message to background script
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
});
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    sendResponse();
  });


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        //alert("good");
        if (request.greeting == "hello")
        createNotification();
    });
function createNotification(){
     var opt = {type: "basic",title: "Your Title",message: "Your  message",iconUrl: "128.png"}
     chrome.notifications.create("notificationName",opt,function(){});

//include this line if you want to clear the notification after 5 seconds
     setTimeout(function(){chrome.notifications.clear("notificationName",function(){});},10000);
}
```

New to chrome extension coding so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Move the code from `chrome.extension.onMessage` callback inside `chrome.runtime.onMessage` callback and remove the former.

Comment: Just tried that - still nothing happened :(

Comment: Does `alert("good")` fire if you uncomment it? Anyway use the debugger on the background page to see what's happening there.

Comment: Ah - Nope not at all.

Comment: Would directory structure have anything to do with it?

Comment: You can't alert in the background page. The alert will appear not on the actual web page but in the context of the chrome extension. You have to ping back to the content script with `executeScript` or invoke a method already in the content script.

Comment: Surprisingly alerts *are* displayed correctly from the background page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCertainWebsitesNeedNotificationAppearTrue` isn't defined anywhere so the code is not executed and the message is not sent.

[image: error]

Use the [devtools debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) to diagnose the problems.

Also move the code from `chrome.extension.onMessage` callback inside `chrome.runtime.onMessage` callback and remove the former.